# Reading repeat block in XML using XPATH and formatting in specific format

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I am using XPATH to format an XML

```
<Test>
<food>apple</food>
<home>hut</home>
</Test>
```

The xpath is specified in properties file

```
[food]=Test/food
[home]=Test/home
```

which converts the xml to

```
[food]=apple
[home]=hut
```

The code used to read properties file and do the formatting is

```
tagsValuesMap=parser.generateTagsValuesMap((fileLoc.append(propertyFilename)).toString());
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : tagsValuesMap.entrySet()) {
            requestMessageToFirco.append(entry.getKey()+" "+entry.getValue()).append("\n");
        }
```

Now my requirement is to have a repeat block 
example

```
<Test>
<food>apple</food>
<home>hut</home>
</Test>
<Test>
<food>orange</food>
<home>wooden</home>
</Test>
```

and the output should be

```
[food]=apple
[food]=orange
[home]=hut
[home]=wooden
```

How this can be achieved? I have tried using ./ or// which did not work

Comment: You'll need to use something like `YAML` or `JSON` to structure your mapping file so that you can provide a root node and then a list of properties.  Otherwise just hardcode a split on the last `/` of the property key - not very extensible but should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following xpath:

```
//Test/food
//Test/home
```

[UPDATE]
Sorry i ignored your last sentence...
This can only work with a root element.
Your data should look like:

```
<root>
<Test>
<food>apple</food>
<home>hut</home>
</Test>
<Test>
<food>orange</food>
<home>wooden</home>
</Test>
</root>
```

then the xpath expression works

Comment: Even after adding one parent tag and using //Test/food the result always gives the first occurance

Comment: can you show your implementation of the generateTagsValuesMap function?

Comment: public Map<String,String> generateTagsValuesMap(String pptyFileLoc){
  XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
  Map<String, String> map = getMap(pptyFileLoc);
  for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
   String expression = entry.getValue();
   try {
    String tagValue = xpath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument);
    map.put(entry.getKey(), tagValue);
   }
   catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }

  return map;